# make menu div element fixed in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a menu div on the left hand side of the page which i am developing in jquery mobile. The problem is that when the page scrolls the menu also scrolls above with the page. I want the menu to be fixed all the time.  How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: fixed;` in CSS:

```
#myDiv {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: When I use position:fixed in the menu css, the page page does not scroll. I want the page o scroll but not the menu.

Comment: In which case you need to set a `min-height` on the containing element.

Comment: I tried min-height, but then too the page is not scrolling.Moreover when I viewed the page on mobile phone(android 2.3.4) , still the menu is getting scrolled with the page.

Comment: Can you edit your original question and include the HTML and CSS of your page. It's hard to give a solution without seeing exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

```
#div_id{
  position:fixed;
  }
```

I think This will help!

Answer (score -1):

```
#myDiv {
position: fixed!important;

  z-index: 1000!important;

top:55px !important

}
```